# Android GridView IfThenElse in OnItemClick

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview, android-gridview

I have two `TextViews` and One `ImageView` in `GridView` and trying to change the background of `ImageView` when user clicks on it. I am able to change the background first time and after that if i click on it nothing is happening. Another issue is if I scroll down I see the background image of other images changing. I want to change the background of image at the specific position. Say If i click on first item image I want to change only for that image. Below is my code. Thanks in advance and I really appreciate your help.

```
GridView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) { 

btnCheckImage1 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckImaget); 
if (btnCheckImage1.getDrawable() != v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.compselection_checked_btn) ) {
btnCheckImage1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.compselection_checked_btn); 
}
else if (btnCheckImage1.getDrawable() == v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.compselection_checked_btn) ) {
btnCheckImage1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.compselection_btn); 
}
} 
});
```

Comment: this kind of object cannot be compared using `==`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the OBJECT.equals(OBJECT) method to compare the drawables.

```
btnCheckImage1 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckImaget); 
if (btnCheckImage1.getDrawable() != v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.compselection_checked_btn) ) {
btnCheckImage1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.compselection_checked_btn); 
}
```

Fires on every item click, so after the first click you won't notice a change unless you do the comparison correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the background of image at the specific position.
>   Say If i click on first item image I want to change only for that
>   image.

For this issue u have to call **yourGridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** in `onItemClick`

> trying to change the background of ImageView when user clicks on it.

For this u have to use `selector` in `res` folder create `drawable` folder in that folder create `selector`

code snippet

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

and in `main layout's gridview` set selector for gridview like tjis

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/your_selector"
```